# Jquery each returning object

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am creating a simple plugin that would create a child element for every element selected.
my problem is that the plugin does not return a reference to the child element. ( or I dont know how to access it )
 here is the plugin ( you can assume that the missing parts are omitted to keep things simple):

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.ui_child = function(options) {

        this.each(function() {  


            return ui_child($(this), options);

        })

    }

    ui_child = function (target, options) {


            return new ui_fn_child(target, options);

    }
    ui_fn_child = function (target, options) {


            this.target = target;

            this.settings= $.extend({}, $.fn.ui_child.defaults, options);

            this.child_create()

            return this.child

    }
     })(jQuery);
```

if I do the following :

```
 var child = $('selector').ui_child();
```

the child variable does not reference anything.
ideally i would like to be able to access it using a variable.
thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you change ui_child method in such a way:

```
$.fn.ui_child = function(options) {
    var children = [];
    this.each(function() {  
        children.push(ui_child($(this), options));
    })
    return children;
}
```

You'll get an array of children here:

```
var child = $('selector').ui_child();
```

Comment: how would i go about getting just the single object instead of an array? I am using this pluggin inside another one in a package i am creating

Comment: What object do you want to get? Last, first, random:)?

Comment: the case i am thinking of is when the function would return only one object ( or an array of 1 if your prefer)

Comment: In ui_child method you iterate through the collection and create one object for each entry from collection. Maybe you want only one object when jQuery selector matched only one element?

Comment: I would like it to create an object for each of the matches and a "child" element which reference is returned. I was under the impression that .each would do that no matter if it the query matches one or many or am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Using the keyword `new` makes the function return the `this` object.

Maybe should you think it in a different way :

```
ui_child = function (target, options) {
        return ui_fn_child(target, options); // no new keyword
};

ui_fn_child = function (target, options) {

        var o = {}; // explicit object creation

        o.target = target;

        o.settings= $.extend({}, $.fn.ui_child.defaults, options);

        o.child_create();

        return o.child;
};
```

Comment: the problem might be with the way I understand the .each function. without it , the plugin does exactly what I want which mean it returns the object desired. however without the each if the selector finds more than one match then all the objects created will be referenced for all the matches not each individually